# How can a undecidable theory be complete?

Tags: logic

I don't understand how a theory can be undecidable (there is no effective procedure for determining if a sentence of the language is a theorem) and also be complete. How do we know all sentences are provable when we don't have a procedure to determine if they are?

Comment: you are first making a false assumption. All languages do not have sentences. Sanskrit, for example, has 'stops', and where a stop is can alter the meaning of the idea or ideas. There are other languages without sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following example: "Let x=0 if the Goldbach conjecture is true and let x=1 if the Goldbach conjecture is false." We **know** that x is either 0 or 1, but we don't know which (yet!).

---

That's exactly what's going on here. Given a [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)) S, let Th(S) be the set of sentences true in S. For each sentence **p**, either **p** is true in S and hence Th(S)-provable or **p** is false in S and hence Th(S)-disprovable (since ~**p** is in Th(S)). We've concluded this without knowing anything about the particulars of the structure S: any structure whatsoever is guaranteed to give rise to a complete theory. Note that in particular this tells us nothing about the *complexity* of Th(S), and indeed there are "perfectly concrete" structures whose theories we know to be undecidable - the standard example being **the natural numbers** (with addition and multiplication), as a consequence of Godel's incompleteness theorem.

- Incidentally, this is the only way complete (consistent) theories arise at all: if T is a complete theory and S is a structure satisfying T then by completeness of T we have T=Th(S) - or rather, *the deductive closure of* T is equal to Th(S), if you use the weaker notion of "complete" here.

---

Now you might object that some epistemological violence is being done to the word "know" here; that's a reasonable response, and leads to the idea of [intuitionistic logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/). But in the classical situation, everything above is perfectly valid - if a bit weird.

Comment: Ah, I guess my confusion came from thinking one has to know whether P is true or not for the theory to be complete.

Comment: @csp2018 Nope! The *theory* has to know, but *we* might not.  (To hopefully make this all less slippery, note that there are many ["levels" of undecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree), and once we know something is undecidable we don't have to throw up our hands but in fact have a bunch of new interesting questions. So I'd say that this isn't actually a cheap trick.)